# JavaScript Regex - Must contain at least any 2 letter in UTF-8

Tags: javascript, regex, string, utf-8

Right now, i'm trying to create a JavaScript Regular Expression with these following conditions:

- Accepts all UTF-8 characters
- Space between words are allowed, how only 1 space and not multiple.
- Allow all symbols for example: !#$%^&*()_-={}[] except: "@"
- No trailing spaces after or before the string.
- Range should be 2-16 characters including spaces
- And must contain at least 2 letter characters in the string.

Here is the Regex I have drawn up so far:

`/^(?![^@]*@)(?![^]*\s\s)\S[^]{0,14}\S$/`

So far this does all of the following except that it doesn't meet the last condition which is that it must contain at least 2 letters. For example:

`"..He" //should be true`

`"He$*" //should be true`

`".." //should be false`

`"*%" //should be false`

`"!#$%^&*()" //should be false since there is no letters`

`"$$tonyMoney™" //should be true`

`"أنا أحب جاف™" //should be true`

`"To" //should be true`

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I doubt `†ø¥™` should be true. Please clarify. Here is what I came up with: [XRegExp solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mtuqjxum/).

Comment: Sorry about that, what I meant to say is that it should be able to contain international characters as well. I had updated my question.

Comment: Is this codegolf or popularity contest?

Comment: I see the Arabic string does not get matched. Still, `¥` is punctuation, not a letter.

Comment: The Arabic example is not valid, it is longer than 16 symbols.

Comment: Sorry about that, it is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this XRegExp-based regex:

```
var rx = XRegExp("^(?![^@]*@)(?![^]*\\s\\s)(?=(?:\\P{L}*\\p{L}){2})\\S[^]{0,14}\\S$");
```

The regex breakdown:

- `^` - string start
- `(?![^@]*@)` - no `@` in the string
- `(?![^]*\\s\\s)` - no two consecutive spaces
- `(?=(?:\\P{L}*\\p{L}){2})` - at least 2 Unicode letters
- `\\S[^]{0,14}\\S` - from 2 to 16 symbols long, no spaces at start and end of string.
- `$` - end of string

See the [regex demo](http://jsfiddle.net/67d50mcb/)

```js
var rx = XRegExp("^(?![^@]*@)(?![^]*\\s\\s)(?=(?:\\P{L}*\\p{L}){2})\\S[\\s\\S]{0,14}\\S$");
document.body.innerHTML = rx.test("..He") + " - must be true<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += rx.test("He$*") + " - must be true<br/>"; 
document.body.innerHTML += rx.test("..") + " - must be false<br/>"; 
document.body.innerHTML += rx.test("*%") + " - must be false<br/>"; 
document.body.innerHTML += rx.test("!#$%^&*()") + " - must be false<br/>"; 
document.body.innerHTML += rx.test("$$tonyMoney™") + " - must be true<br/>"; 
document.body.innerHTML += rx.test("To") + " - must be true<br/>"; 
document.body.innerHTML += rx.test("أنا أحب جاف™") + " - must be true<br/>";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/2.0.0/xregexp-all-min.js"></script>
```